# How to direct DataContract to use xs:time for DateTime or TimeSpan field?

Tags: c#, xml, datetime, serialization, xsd

How can I make XsdDataContractExporter use xs:time type for my DateTime field?

I need to be able to deserialize string of a HH:mm:ss format (e.g. "21:59:59") in my code using DataContract serialization. This is not a problem when using data type DateTime and marking it appropriately:

```
[DataContract]
public class TestClass
{
    [DataMember(Name = "Begin")]
    public DateTime TimeField;
}
```

Serializationa and deserialization works fine.
Now I need to be able to xsd validate the string against automatically generated xsd from the type:

```
XsdDataContractExporter xsdExp = new XsdDataContractExporter();
xsdExp.Export(typeof(T));
XmlSchemaSet xsdSet = xsdExp.Schemas;
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(stringReader);
xDoc.Validate(xsdSet, null);
```

The validation fails since XsdDataContractExporter uses xs:dateTime type for DateTime and I get following error:

> Additional information: The 'Begin' element is invalid - The value
>   '05:00:00' is invalid according to its datatype
>   'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:dateTime' - The string '05:00:00' is
>   not a valid DateTime value.

Using TimeSpan doesn't help either - as then XsdDataContractExporter uses xs:duration (and on top of that DataContractDeserializer cannot deserialize TimeSpan from the HH:mm:ss string).

Is there a way how to keep using DataContractSerializer and XsdDataContractExporter and be able to deserialize those strings? We are using dozens and dozens of convoluted settings types and xmls - and this is the only case where those utils fails (so I'd like to avoid writting custom validation and deserialization for all the types)

Comment: The only idea I had was to use string data type - to relax the xsd validation, and then deserialize in OnDeserialized method. This is howeever very ugly hack :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used string DataContract (de)serialization and then timespan parsing within custom method:

```
public class TestClass
{
    //Storing as string due to xsd validation as XsdDataContractExporter is 
    // using either xs:dataTime for DataTime or xs:duration for TimeSpan. xs:time is not used
    // And so xsd validation were failing for string in format 'HH:mm:ss' (despite DataContract can deserialize them as DateTime)
    [DataMember(Name = "Begin")]
    public string _beginString;
    [DataMember(Name = "End")]
    public string _endString;

    public TimeSpan Begin { get; private set; };
    public TimeSpan End{ get; private set; };

    [OnDeserialized]
    private void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
    {
        this.Begin = TimeSpan.Parse(_beginString);
        this.End = TimeSpan.Parse(_endString);
    }
}
```